# Customizing WizardNewFileCreationPage and WizardNewFolderMainPage: changing the default tree

Tags: eclipse, tree, eclipse-rcp, wizard, customization

We have created two custom wizard pages that extend from WizardNewFileCreationPage and WizardNewFolderMainPage. But we need to modify the default tree selection dialog (we need to show only a subset of the current tree elements). How can we do it ?
I've found that attribute resourceGroup can't be modified. Creating a new class frow scratch is the only way?.

Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly found out that you cannot modify the `resourceGroup` as it is a private member of `WizardNewFileCreationPage` and `WizardNewFolderMainPage`. Because of its accessibility you can't even **override** `public void createControl(Composite parent)`.

As far as I know there is no `extension point` to alter this behavior. Unfortunately you have to rewrite/create the whole thing.